# Server Sent Events detect client disconnect?

Tags: python, server-sent-events

I have a lighttpd server with python installed, its using cgi. I'm able to set up a connection with Server Sent Events, but I'm unsure of how to detect if the client disconnects. I read somewhere that its impossible to tell whether a client disconnects or not, unless you send a message to detect it. I'm unsure of how to detect the client disconnect after sending a message. Whenever I send a message I just do...

```
print(message)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Do I have to read stdin to check if the client disconnected or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next version of lighttpd (1.4.40) detects if a client disconnects and sends a TERM signal to the CGI if the CGI is still running.